# Replicating Excel's "sort by", "then by" behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

What would be the best way to replicate Excel's sorting for JS?

Let's say I have an array with items:

```
[6,0.75]
[6,0.81]
[9,0.75]
[4,0.20]
```

Sorting them by first key is easy enough but how to replicate "then by" sorting? Excel would spit out the following result with 1st key desc and second key desc:

```
[9,0.75]
[6,0.81]
[6,0.75]
[4,0.20]
```

Comment: You will get this same result with native JS `Array.sort` method too, when sorting "2D-array". `sort` will go deeper to inner arrays, if it meets two equal values at the first index. I think you could improve your question by representing for example a 4x4 array, and then require to sort in order of 3, 0, 2, 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are simpler ways of doing this for the given example, but in the general case you can pass a function to the sort method that will compare each pair of values in a specified order. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKYj9/3/))

```
var arr1 = [[6, 0.75], [6, 0.81], [9, 0.75], [4, 0.20]],
    arr2 = [[6, 0.75], [6, 0.81], [9, 0.75], [4, 0.20]],
people = [{name: 'Jim', age: 40}, {name: 'Sally', age: 35},
          {name: 'Tim', age: 20}, {name: 'Jim', age: 72}];

function orderedComparison(indices) {
    return function(a, b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            if (a[indices[i]] > b[indices[i]]) return 1;
            if (a[indices[i]] < b[indices[i]]) return -1;
            // (if a == b, check next index)
        }
    }
}
// sort by first item in each pair, then 2nd
arr1.sort(orderedComparison([0, 1]));
console.log(arr1);
// sort by 2nd item then 1st
arr2.sort(orderedComparison([1, 0]));
console.log(arr2); 
people.sort(orderedComparison(['name', 'age']));
console.log(people);​
```

Note that the following, which simply sorts by the lower-priority key first then the higher-priority key, will probably work but is [not guaranteed to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
arr1.sort(function(a, b) {return a[1] - b[1]});
arr1.sort(function(a, b) {return a[0] - b[0]});
```

Comment: I think this does exactly the same thing as Excel's `sort by...then by`. +1 : ).

Comment: @Teemu More or less, though if you have both text and numbers in the same field then the behaviour will differ from Excel (which sees any text as < any number)

Comment: Yep, JS uses ASCII order, but it's easy to change in the function, when needed. Thanks for this, I'm going to use it : ).

Comment: actually according to JS none of the following is true: 0 > 'a', 0 < 'a', 0 == 'a'. So my sort function will not deal that well with mixed types in the same 'column', but can be adapted as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate this functionality by scaling each subindex so their magnitudes do not overlap and do a standard comparison using `Array.sort();`

This jsfiddle demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/Jd2ne/2/

Hint: If you do not know what magnitudes are it is the exponent of ten when you write the number out in scientific notation. I. e: 6 = 6 * 10^0 => 6's magnitude is zero.

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you want this method to work with non-numerical input you will have to convert the input to numbers, but that is how regular sorting works anyway, only difference is that here you will have to assign the number values to represent different input yourself.